# Problem with created_at, updated_at, deleted_at

Tags: database, laravel

I'm using laravel. My table has `..., created_at, updated_at, deleted_at` columns.
First, I insert `created_at` into table:

```
DB::table('table')->insert([
    ...
    "created_at" => Carbon::now()
])
```

Now `created_at` OK,  both `updated_at, deleted_at` are null.
Then I update `updated_at`:

```
DB::table('table')->where(...)->update([
    ...
    "updated_at" => Carbon::now()
])
```

In result: `created_at` down 5 hours (I've tested with +0 GMT and -5 GMT and got the same), `updated_at` correct, `deleted_at` = `updated_at` though I did nothing with that column. What did I do wrong? Thank you for any help.

My config/app.php: `...'timezone' => 'UTC',...`

Comment: Could you add your config/app.php code and more details about your environment ?

Comment: yeah , you need to modify your config/app.php putting yout timezone

Comment: My `config/app.php`: `...'timezone' => 'UTC',...`
`.env` just has:
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

Answer (score 0):

When changing the time zone in the config.php file not working, just do

```
php artisan config:cache
```

then it should work, unless you could try to use "date" from PHP and change the timezone there

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin') //setting timezone

date(now()) //getting the date
```

here is a  [list of supported time zones](https://www.php.net/manual/de/timezones.php).
Hope it works